# Different marker colors for start and end points in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot lines on a plot between two point tuples. I have following arrays:

```
start_points = [(54.6, 35.2), (55.5, 32.7), (66.5, 23.7), (75.5, 47.8), (89.3, 19.7)]
end_points = [(38.9, 44.3), (46.7, 52.2), (72.0, 1.4), (62.3, 18.9), (80.8, 26.2)]
```

So what I am trying to do is drawing lines between points at same index like a line from (54.6, 35.2) to (38.9, 44.3), another line from (55.5, 32.7) to (46.7, 52.2) and so on.

I achieved this by plotting `zip(start_points[:5], end_points[:5])`, but I want different marker styles for start and end points of lines. I want start_points to be green circle, and end_points to be blue x for example. Is this possible?

Comment: What is `pass_start`? How are you plotting the result? It would be *much* easier if you just showed the code you are using to obtain the plot and edit the image in paint/similar program to show us what you'd like to obtain instead.

Comment: @Bakuriu I edited it. Sorry, I changed the original variable names but forgot to change the variable names in zip part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is to first plot the line (`plt.plot`) and then plot the markers using a scatter plot (`plt.scatter`).

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

start_points = [(54.6, 35.2), (55.5, 32.7), (66.5, 23.7), (75.5, 47.8), (89.3, 19.7)]
end_points = [(38.9, 44.3), (46.7, 52.2), (72.0, 1.4), (62.3, 18.9), (80.8, 26.2)]

for line in zip(start_points, end_points):
    line = np.array(line)
    plt.plot(line[:, 0], line[:, 1], color='black', zorder=1)
    plt.scatter(line[0, 0], line[0, 1], marker='o', color='green', zorder=2)
    plt.scatter(line[1, 0], line[1, 1], marker='x', color='red', zorder=2)
```

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much.